# RESTful Webservice Using Spring Framework

Tags: spring, web-services, rest, spring-mvc, spring-rest

I have written some RESTful webservices using Spring Framework (by reading posts online / video tutorials etc.) , however I still have some doubts.

When we write a **web-application using Spring MVC module** we use **controller code**, similar to below:

```
@Controller
public class SimpleController {

    @RequestMapping("/welcome")
        ModelAndView handleIncomingWelcomeReq() {

        ModelAndView mw = new ModelAndView("WelcomePage","welcomeKey","WelcomeKey's value!");

        return mw;
    }
```

}

In the above code there is ModelAndView object which this controller returns, and this can be invoked like this URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/contextRoot/welcome
```

**Now, if we exclude the "view" part and return just the model doesn't it act like a web service?**

So my doubt is, in Spring do we used the same API/jar's to create web-application or RESTful web services?

The things which I read is that for Spring REST support, it has annotation `@RestController` annotation (which itself is like `@Contoller` + `@ResponseBody` annotations).

So what is the difference in which the implementation of REST WS and web-applications differs in Spring Framework?

Can anyone help me understand this?

Comment: I am not sure why this question is voted to be closed. I did explain the homework I have done before asking this question. It may be naive question for experienced developer, but for beginners might make sense.  If anything else is expected to be edited to this question, I am willing to do, but please help clear the doubts. Best Regards

Comment: I would say it's too broad of a question. Rest is jax-rs and webservices is jax-ws.

Comment: @Nicholas: Thanks for your response. My question is specific to Spring framework support for RESTful WS. The confusion i have in understand if creating RESTful WS using Spring, do we use the same API which are used in creating Spring MVC based web-application?

Comment: chat Java::chat ><> & Chips if you want. Rest just exposes a "REST" endpoint, a front-end is not part of it. MVC would be responding to browser requests with the @Controller as you mentioned. Some client-side frameworks interface with REST endpoints to get data. MVC is a server-side framework.

Comment: @Nicholas: Thanks for your reply. I read some more documentation, so I believe it is just the difference in the annotations and the response which is sent back decided, the underlying Spring support is same (it uses spring-web, spring-mvcweb modules.

Answer (score 0):

Yes we can write RestService & web application using Spring. Use @RestController to expose a REST service and @Controller for web application.

@RestController is a meta-annotation with @Controller and @ResponseBody. @Controller will search through the registered ViewResolvers, whereas @RestController will not.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Controller
public class SimpleController {
@RequestMapping("/welcome", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces="application/json")
    public @ResponseBody JSONObject handleIncomingWelcomeReq() {
    JSONObject j = new JSONObject();
    j.put("welcomeKey", "WelcocmeKey's value!");
    return j;
}
```

Here is the code which returns response in json mostly user id  Rest Apis.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use @Controller instead of @RestController, as @RestController, won't scan your views. So, in case if your application has it's own views and also needs to expose it's services, you can use @Controller along with the @ResponseBody annotations, with output as JSON.

Another option is to have completely different URL for RESTful webservices, where a different controller will handle the request. These different controllers can be annotated with @RestController.